# File transfer using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-transfer

I am trying to copy some files from one folder to the other using JavaScript and NodeJS. I am reading the file names from a text file to achieve this but only the last file is getting transferred. `FileNames.txt` has the names of the files that are present in `F:/Some Folder/Origin Folder` and I want to copy these files inside `F:/Some Folder/Target Folder`. The `count` variable is used to verify the number of files transferred.

```
function readFileContents() {
  fs.readFile(
    "F:/Some Folder/FileNames.txt",
    "utf8",
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        data.split("\n").forEach(d => transferFiles(d));
      }
      console.log(count);
    }
  );
}

function transferFiles(fileName) {
  fs.cp(
    `F:/Some Folder/Origin Folder/${fileName}`,
    `F:/Some Folder/Target Folder/${fileName}`,
    err => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(`Transferred ${fileName}`);
        count++;
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why are there double slashes? Doesn't that give you any errors?

Comment: Add the logs from console and the contents of *FileNames.txt* to your question.

Comment: You log `count` _synchronously_, before the files have been copied _asynchronously_. You cannot therefore possibly see the correct number of copied files.

Comment: @ParkingMaster added double slashes so that there is one left in the string at run time to escape a "special character". Though the code is working the same with a single slash.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen This process is asynchronous, that's why only the last file is getting transferred. However, I am not able to convert my code to account for this asynchronous behavior.

Comment: The forward slash like you are using should not be doubled.  It's not a special character in any way in Javascript strings.  So, when you double it, you get two of them in the resulting string which is not what you want for a path separator.

Comment: Perhaps you are getting confused by the nature of the `transferFiles()` function in how you call it.   It will return long before the `fs.cp()` operations is done.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes you are correct. That's why only the last file is getting copied and the other files are not. As far as the double slashes are concerned, the last file is still getting transferred.

Comment: So, your code `data.split("\n").forEach(d => transferFiles(d));` will start all the transfers and return immediately without waiting for ANY of them to be done.  The code you show has no ability to actually know when they are all done and see what the final count is because you aren't tracking when everything is done.

Comment: @jfriend00 so I need to find a way to wait for the transfer to finish before going to read the next filename. Will async await work?

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
data.split("\n").forEach(d => transferFiles(d));
```

will start all the transfers and return immediately without waiting for ANY of them to be done. The code you show has no ability to actually know when they are all done and see what the final count is because you aren't tracking when everything is done.

I would suggest using `await fs.promises.cp(...)` which is a [promise-version](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisescpsrc-dest-options) of the function and then you can `await` each one and carry them out in sequence and more easily know when they are all done.  Do, not use `.forEach()` with asynchronous code because it is not promise-aware and will not respect promises.  Instead, use just a plain `for` loop or `for/of` loop, both of which are promise and await-friendly.

And, while you're at it, you may as well switch to `const data = await fs.promises.readFile(...)` also so you consistently use promises to manage your asynchronous operations, not plain callbacks.  Better to not mix promises with plain callbacks.

Here's how you would sequence these operations with promises:

```
const fsp = fs.promises;

async function readFileContents() {
    const data = await fsp.readFile("F:/Some Folder/FileNames.txt", "utf8");
    const files = data.split("\n");
    let count = 0;
    for (let file of files) {
        await transferFile(file);
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}

async function transferFiles(fileName) {
    try {
        await fsp.cp(
            `F:/Some Folder/Origin Folder/${fileName}`,
            `F:/Some Folder/Target Folder/${fileName}`
        );
        console.log(`Transferred ${fileName}`);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    }        
}
```

The caller of `readFileContents()` would receive a promise back and that promise will resolve to the count of the number of files copied or it will reject with an error.  The caller can use either `await` or `.then()` on that returned promise to get the count.